# not sure which testcases fails my code

Tags: python, testing, testcase

I have found the following code in CodeWars and have written the description too. It says my code passes 8 testcases and not the 9th one. Can someone give me an idea what is wrong or how should I proceed to this? I had only access to the four testcases I have in answer.
https://www.codewars.com/kata/555615a77ebc7c2c8a0000b8/discuss#label-issue

```
'''
The new "Avengers" movie has just been released! There are a lot of people at the cinema
box office standing in a huge line. Each of them has a single 100, 50 or 25 dollars bill.
A "Avengers" ticket costs 25 dollars. Vasya is currently working as a clerk. He wants to
sell a ticket to every single person in this line. Can Vasya sell a ticket to each person
and give the change if he initially has no money and sells the tickets strictly in the
order people follow in the line? Return YES, if Vasya can sell a ticket to each person
and give the change. Otherwise return NO.
Examples:
### Python ###
tickets([25, 25, 50]) # => YES
tickets([25, 100])
         # => NO. Vasya will not have enough money to give change to 100 dollars
'''

def tickets(people):
    sum = 0
    for p in people:
        if p < 25:
            return 'NO'
        if p == 25:
            sum += p
        elif p > 25:
            if (sum - p) <0 :
                return 'NO'
            else:
                sum += p
    return 'YES'

print(tickets([25, 25, 50])) #YES
print(tickets([25, 100])) #NO
print(tickets([25, 25, 50, 50, 50])) #YES
print(tickets([25, 25, 25, 25, 50, 100, 50])) #YES
```

Comment: Your final else statement is the problem. The sum gets bigger by 25, not by p. She does return the change, doesn't she?

Comment: my current program passes the tests shown in the code though. can you think of a testcase that my code will fail?

Comment: well just realized without that else clause still my four testcases shown passes but yet I don't pass the unknown 9th testcase in codewars @Ev.Kounis

Comment: The else has to stay but reformatted like: sum += 25. Try it and you should be able to pass the 9th too.

Comment: doesn'T pass the 9th one!

Answer (score 2):

The if statement is also wrong. Think about the testcase [25, 50, 100] for the sum += p mistake and the following scenario [25, 50] for the if statement mistake. With the code bellow, both issues should be fixed.

```
def tickets(people):
    register = {'25s': 0, '50s': 0, '100s': 0}
    cash_in_register = 0
    for p in people:
        if p < 25:
            return 'NO'
        elif p == 25:
            cash_in_register += p
            register['25s'] += 1
        else:
            if (p - cash_in_register) <= 25: # do you have enough money for change?
                if p == 50 and register['25s'] >= 1:
                    register['50s'] += 1
                    register['25s'] -= 1
                    cash_in_register += 25
                elif (p == 100 and register['50s'] >= 1 and register['25s'] >= 1):
                    register['100s'] += 1
                    register['50s'] -= 1
                    register['25s'] -= 1
                    cash_in_register += 25
                elif (p == 100 and register['25s'] >= 3):
                    register['100s'] += 1
                    register['25s'] -= 3
                    cash_in_register += 25
                else:
                    return 'NO'
            else:
                return 'NO'
    return 'YES'
```

Let me know! ☺

Comment: please try your code in codewars platform before submitting it. You code didn't work

Comment: So i have to go and create a profile in Codewars now? What was the problem with it? The 4 cases you supplied still work + i explained to you what you did wrong and fixed it..

Comment: It doesn't tell what the problem is unfortunately!

Comment: it does pass all tests now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you don't look at the actual bills you have.

look at the testcase [25, 25, 50, 50, 50]: It should produce a "NO", but if I understand your Code correctly, yours answers "YES".

After the second 50, there is 50$ in your sum, but its one 50$ Bill. So when another customer comes in with 50$, the cashier can't give 25$ back.

Comment: so very true.. This changes the ballgame entirely. I will adapt my code.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "not sure which test cases fail"; I'm guessing you mean what you are seeing in the test console is simply:

```
Test Results:
 Test Passed
 Test Passed
```

Right? You can see exactly what lists are being passed into the `tickets` function as `people` by adding a print statement:

```
def tickets(people):
    print(people)
    ...
```

When the tests run, the console will print out what's being passed into it.

```
Test Results:
 Log
 [25, 25, 50]
 Test Passed
```

These are all the test cases anyway:

```
[25, 25, 50]
[25, 100]
[25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25]
[50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
[100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
[25, 25, 25, 25, 50, 100, 50]
[50, 100, 100]
[25, 25, 100]
[25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 50, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100]
[25, 25, 50, 50, 100]
[25, 50, 50]
[25, 25, 25, 100]
[25, 50, 25, 100]
[25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 100, 100]
```